# How to convert Array into object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I wanted to create a customer's dictionary using reduce function, I am doing it using forEach

```
const customers = 
  [ { name: 'ZOHAIB', phoneNumber: '0300xxxxx', other: 'anything'     } 
  , { name: 'Zain',   phoneNumber: '0321xxxxx', other: 'other things' } 
  ] 

let customersDictionary = {};
customers.forEach(customer => {
  customersDictionary = {
      ...customersDictionary,
      [ customer.phoneNumber ]: {name: customer.name},
      };
```

I wanted the same output but using reduce method.

```
customersDictionary = 
  { "0300xxxxx": {"name": "ZOHAIB"}
  , "0321xxxxx": {"name": "Zain"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
const customers = [
  { name: "ZOHAIB", phoneNumber: "0300xxxxx", other: "anything" },
  { name: "Zain", phoneNumber: "0321xxxxx", other: "other things" },
];

const customersDictionary = customers.reduce(
  (acc, { phoneNumber, name }) => ({
    ...acc,
    [phoneNumber]: { name },
  }),
  {}
);
```

Comment: I like `{ phoneNumber, ...rest }`. I didn't know the rest operator also works with objects.

Comment: thanks, he needs that as the objects inside the array also contains other properties other than `name`

Comment: {"03005359279": {"other": "anything","name": "ZOHAIB"}, "03212744193": {"other":"other thing", "name": "Muhammad Zohaib"}}

Comment: return 'other' property too which is not required

Comment: this solution will include everything in the objects except for the `phoneNumber` which are included in the object keys

Comment: I corrected it to only use `name` and ignore the 'other' properties

Comment: @Oussama thanks dear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `reduce`. It's a one-liner with `Array.prototype.map` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```
Object.fromEntries(customers.map(c => [c.phoneNumber, { name: c.name }]));
```

The variant using `reduce`:

```
customers.reduce((acc, c) => {
  acc[c.phoneNumber] = { name: c.name };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Just a little tunning for reduce variant
`customers.reduce((acc, {phoneNumber,  name}) => ({...acc, [phoneNumber]: { name } }), {});`

Comment: @Ffire Yes, but I don't want to copy the other answer and IMO the reducer in the other answer is better than mine.